# Insert data into two tables (foreign key joined) from one form in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a form in CakePHP as following 
**addticket.ctp**

```
    <html>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('Ticket', array('url' => array('controller' => 'tickets', 'action' =>'addtickets'),
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));
    echo $this->Form->input('title',array('label'=>'Title'));
    echo $this->Form->input('attachment', array('between'=>'<br />','type'=>'file',

        'label'=>'Attachment'));
    echo $this->Form->input('stepstoreproduce',array('label'=>'Steps To Reproduce'));
    echo $this->Form->input('category',array(
        'label'=>'Category',
        'options'=>array(
            'IT Support',
            'IT HelpDesk'
            )));
    echo $this->Form->input('priority',array(
        'label'=>'Priority',
        'options'=>array(
            'Low',
            'Medium',
            'High'
            )));
    echo $this->Form->input('Comment.comment',array(
        'type'=>'textarea',
        'label'=>'Comments'
        ));
    echo $form->input('public',array('type'=>'radio',
    'options' => array(
        '1'=>'Yes',
        '0'=>'No',
    ),
    'default'=>'0'));
    echo $form->input('created_by',array('value'=>$_SESSION['Auth']['User']['id'],'type'=>'hidden'));

    echo $this->Form->end('Submit Ticket');

?>
</html>
```

And I have model ticket.php with following code

```
var $hasMany = array(
    'Comment' => array(
        'className'     => 'Comment',
        'foreignKey'    => 'ticket_id'
        )
);
```

And I have tickets_controller with addticket() function as follows

```
 if ($this->Ticket->saveAll($this->data)){
            $this->Session->setFlash('Ticket created');
        } 
        else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Cannot create a ticket');
        }
```

**Problem**
The problem is that there are two tables in my database:
1.tickets
2.Comments (ticket_id is foreign key )

I want to insert tickets data to `tickets` table and comments data to `comments` table. As I know that changing name to `Comment.comment` will insert data in comments table.

But I want to add `userid` and `ticket_id` in comment table and
 `created_by` in tickets & comments both.

Please Help
Thanks in advance

Comment: If i were you, i would not make the hidden user_id field an input field... Unless you are using security component, you are asking for problems! Populate it using the controller, or use beforeSave in the model to manipulate the data being saved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to explicitly put a Model name in front of every input field you have. For example:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Ticket.title',array('label'=>'Title'));
echo $this->Form->input('Ticket.attachment', array('between'=>'<br />','type'=>'file',

    'label'=>'Attachment'));
```

CakePHP will automatically set ticket_id in your Comment data.
See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array for more detail.

And I think you should set the user_id in the controller instead of set it as a hidden field in a view like:

```
$this->data['Ticket']['created_by'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
$this->data['Comment']['created_by'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
```