# Fatal error: Call to undefined method View::redirect() cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am developing an application in CakePHP 1.3. Everything is working fine but one error is there. 
When I use `redirect()` in my `.ctp` page it gives error

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined method DebugView::redirect()
```

As redirect is working fine when I use it in controller.
I have included helpers as follows in my AppController

```
  var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form','Session');
```

Please help
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You never redirect (or output any header if possible) in the view layer.
Use the controller to do so.
The view then should only render the output according to the desired output format (html, xml, json, ...). Header stuff is part of the reponse and responsibility of the controller (and in 2.x the response class itself).

So your observation that it will work with controllers and not inside views is correct.
"Call to undefined method" always is a good indicator for a method not being available in this scope. 
Redirects being part of the "logic" makes them only available in controllers and components. Never ever in the view (output after all logic happened).

Comment: Then what alternate I should use. PHP header??

Comment: no alternate. correct your faulty code and only use redirect() from your controller and or components. if you feel the need to do it in your view, you got it all wrong and need to refactor your code.

Comment: I am fetching the data from database and then extracting the values from array using foreach in view. And then comparing particular field with another field and then if success stay on page else redirect. I am thinking my code is not faulty but according to situation I needed!

Comment: Can you please answer my http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868854/insert-data-into-two-tables-foreign-key-joined-from-one-form-in-cakephp question?.

Comment: I disagree. You could iterate and make that decision in the controller action.

Comment: $this->set('viewtickets', $this->Ticket->read()); If I am iterating it in controller with foreach ($viewtickets as $viewticket). But it is giving error. that viewtickets not found. :(

Comment: @Usman Yes, because `read()` takes two arguments. Please check the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-read).

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
$this->redirect( 'url, absolute or relative here' );
```

Done.